# How to echo html tag in blade of Laravel

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel-5

I want to echo button to my blade but I don't know how to do. So, how to do that? Thanks you.

```
<td class="nowrap">{!! $order->status=='0'?
    @php
    echo '<button class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</button>';
    @endphp:
    @php
    echo '<button class="btn btn-success">Active</button>';
    @endphp
    !!}
</td>
```

Comment: Why do you have @php tags around it when you just have html in it?

Comment: You also can use normal php syntax, <?php ?> and write your code

Comment: hi @Loko and  ashanrupasinghe, i solved it ^^, thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using two ways first use if condition like below

```
<td class="nowrap">
@if( $order->status == '0' )
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</button>
@else
    <button class="btn btn-success">Active</button>
@endif
</td>
```

The second and proper way for use ternary operator on blade

```
<td class="nowrap">
      {!! $order->status=='0' ? '<button class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</button>' : '<button class="btn btn-success">Active</button>' !!}
</td>
```

I hope the second way is perfect for used ternary operator on blade.

Comment: glad to hear it help full for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can put HTML code in PHP variable as a string and that variable should be placed in `{!! !!}` braces.

Example:

`{!! $text !!}`

Answer (score 2):

```
<td class="nowrap">
   @if($order->status=='0')
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</button>
   @else
      <button class="btn btn-success">Active</button>
   @endif
</td>
```

or

```
<td class="nowrap">
   <button class="btn btn-{{($order->status=='0') ? 'danger' : 'success'}}">{{($order->status=='0') ? 'Inactive' : 'Active'}}</button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

In blade you could do something like this:

```
<td class="nowrap">
    @if($order->status=='0')
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</button>';
    @else
        <button class="btn btn-success">Active</button>';
    @endif 
</td>
```